# jquery .find() syntax error

Tags: jquery

Can anyone spot the error that is causing the results to not appear?

If I remove the code between the "FROM HERE" and "TO HERE" comments, everything works (well, it appears on screen at least). I'm pretty sure the problem is with the .find() syntax.

Code runs on $(document).ready

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php",
    data: 'request=index_list_contacts_for_client&user_id=' + user_id,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#contact_table').html(data);
        var tbl = $('#injected_table_of_contacts');
    /* ************** FROM HERE *********************** */
        tbl.find("div").each(function() {
            $(this).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 400,
                width: 600,
                modal: true,
                buttons: 
                    {
                        Okay: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        Cancel: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    },
                close: function() {
                    alert('DialogClose fired');
                }
            })
        });
    /* ************** TO HERE *********************** */
    }
});
```

Comment: First, are you seeing any error messages? If so, paste those in the question. Second, you're calling `find` just fine: you need to fix your JS syntax errors first and then see if you're still having a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Cancel` button is incorrect.

```
                buttons: {
                    Okay: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    // you have to put cancel here
                    Cancel: function() {}
                },
                // It should not be here
                //{
                //    Cancel: function() {
                //        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                //    }
                //},
```

Comment: The error is so blatantly obvious in retrospect - I hate to confess how long I was struggling with it. Thank you.